# Control.Location.Y Not Returning Correct Position

Tags: c#, winforms, location

I am a newbie to c#. I am trying to make a list as shown in the blue area of the following image:
[image]

I have used a simple Panel instead of listbox because I needed to add controls with every entry. Now, the list you see in the image is the one that I made to test so its just hardcoded values. But now when I am trying to make each entry move dynamically below the last one, I cannot get it to happen. I have used Control.Location.Y but it returns the Y coordinate of the 2nd entry each time and the entries overlap each other.

Here is the code:

```
public void enterItems (listingPanel list, int loc)
    {
        items.Add(list);
        int lastIndex = items.Count - 1;
        int newLoc = items[lastIndex].Location.Y + 52;
        this.Controls.Add(items[lastIndex]);
        if (lastIndex >= 1)
            items[lastIndex].Location = new Point(0, newLoc);
        Console.WriteLine("index: " + lastIndex + ", location Y: " + (items[lastIndex].Location.Y + 52) + " last loc: " + items[lastIndex].Location.Y + "Total: " + items.Count);
    }
```

This is the definition of addItems(int) that is calling the enterItems() method:

```
private void addItems(int loc)
    {
        listingPanel lists = new listingPanel("Shashlik", Convert.ToString(20), Convert.ToString(2));
        listing.enterItems(lists, loc);
    }
```

This is the event that is calling the addItems(int) method:

```
private void sellBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //for (int i = 0; i<1000; i = i+52)
            addItems(0);
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

First you add an item to the list, then you want to position it relative to the previous item.

However since you obtain the index of the last item *after* adding the *new* item to the list, you're actually positioning an item relative to *itself*!

Beware: if you try to fix the issue by putting `int lastIndex = items.Count - 1` *before* adding the item, it will of course throw an exception because `lastIndex == -1`, so you'll have to provide the Y-position for the first item in some other way.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the issue! What I did next was just to subtract 1 from lastIndex in the if condition.
if (lastIndex >= 1) { items[lastIndex].Location = new Point(0, items[lastIndex-1].Location.Y + 52);}